# List comprehension with Set comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of list which contains set in them, what I want is list of list with a single set item.

i.e. `["item1", "item2", {1,2,3,4}, "item4"]` --> `[["item1", "item2", 1, "item4"],["item1", "item2", 2, "item4"],["item1", "item2", 3, "item4"],["item1", "item2", 4, "item4"]]`

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: What if the list you start with has multiple sets? Or is it always a single set? And does it always sit at index 2 of the list?

Comment: Remember, [order is not guaranteed with python sets](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sets/#:~:text=Set%20is%20an%20unordered%20collection%20of%20data%20type%20that%20is%20iterable)

Comment: @Grismar 
1,2:  It won't have multiple sets
3: Always at the same index

Comment: @Samathingamajig I don't care about the order for this, but that is a good point that you're making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have a single set you need to expand in this way and it always sits at index 2 in the original list:

```
data = ["item1", "item2", {1, 2, 3, 4}, "item4"]

result = [data[:2] + [x] + data[3:] for x in data[2]]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['item1', 'item2', 1, 'item4'], ['item1', 'item2', 2, 'item4'], ['item1', 'item2', 3, 'item4'], ['item1', 'item2', 4, 'item4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more generalized approach that the other answer,

```
data = ["item1", "item2", {1,2,3,4}, "item4"]
sets = list(filter(lambda item:True if type(item) == set else False, data))
list(map(data.remove, sets))
new_data = [data + [s] for set_ in sets for s in set_]
```

Output -

```
[['item1', 'item2', 'item4', 1],
 ['item1', 'item2', 'item4', 2],
 ['item1', 'item2', 'item4', 3],
 ['item1', 'item2', 'item4', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["item1", "item2", {1, 2, 3, 4}, "item4"]
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    if type(item) == set:
        for i in list(item):
            print(data[:idx] + [i] + data[idx+1:])
```

Output:

```
['item1', 'item2', 1, 'item4']
['item1', 'item2', 2, 'item4']
['item1', 'item2', 3, 'item4']
['item1', 'item2', 4, 'item4']
```